How to use Github actions with aws-vault for Terraform deployment?
At the moment we use:
aws-vault exec xxx-office-admin -- terraform deploy

to deploy the Terraform to the aws environment. Currently we are running this locally, is there an easy way to use GitHub actions to authenticate and deploy into AWS Environment? Have heard of OIDC provider for GitHub but wondering is this the best choice?
